# Error while running websockets on jetty

Tags: atmosphere, jetty-9

I am running atmosphere on jetty 2.9.1. While making websocket connection with the server I am getting error in onSuspend() event as

```
ERROR org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor - onRequest() java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING.
```

I am using atmosphere-jersey 2.1.0. and atmosphere-redis 2.1.0 for broadcasting messages. 
Following is the full stack trace

```
Atmosphehre onSuspend(): 04-03-2014 15:40:52.035[qtp1792381773-19] ERROR
org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor - onRequest()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.lockMsg(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:120) ~[websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.sendString(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:372) ~[websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.atmosphere.container.version.Jetty9WebSocket.write(Jetty9WebSocket.java:41) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:217) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:42) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:521) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:307) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:135) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:96) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:320) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:163) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:174) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:95) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Jetty9AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.service(Jetty9AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:179) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1782) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:421) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$2.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:274) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:269) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:292) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Jetty9WebSocketHandler.onWebSocketText(Jetty9WebSocketHandler.java:77) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:127) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:64) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:121) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:169) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:302) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:204) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:223) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:260) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.read(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:500) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:409) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505) [jetty-io-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
04-03-2014 15:40:52.037[qtp1792381773-19] WARN  org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor - Failed invoking AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport()
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:166) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:174) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:95) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Jetty9AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.service(Jetty9AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:179) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1782) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:421) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$2.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:274) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:269) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:292) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Jetty9WebSocketHandler.onWebSocketText(Jetty9WebSocketHandler.java:77) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:127) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:64) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:121) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:169) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:302) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:204) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:223) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:260) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.read(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:500) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:409) [websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505) [jetty-io-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.lockMsg(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:120) ~[websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.sendString(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:372) ~[websocket-common-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.atmosphere.container.version.Jetty9WebSocket.write(Jetty9WebSocket.java:41) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:217) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:42) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:521) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:307) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58) ~[jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:135) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:96) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:320) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:163) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
04-03-2014 15:40:52.038[qtp1792381773-19] WARN  org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING Status 500 Message Server Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try the latest 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT? I've logged the error [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1491)

SNapshot are available [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Downloading-Atmosphere%27s-SNAPSHOT). Let me know the result.

-- Jeanfrancois